# create url in text string using php

Tags: php, html, mysql, url, hyperlink

I am creating weblinks on my site using PHP. Why do this and not do it manually - because I am accessing link information that is pulled from a mysql database. The query pulls out the data fine, the only trouble I am having is creating a text string with a link.

Two variables; $Loc_Name is the text I want to display, $Loc_Web is the URL.

Now i found the following which puts in the URL fine, but this does not display the text in the $Loc_Name output. How can I display the $Loc_Name value for the $Loc_Web url?

```
$Web_Link = ereg_replace("[[:alpha:]]+://[^<>[:space:]]+[[:alnum:]/]","<a href=\"\\0\">\\0</a>", $Loc_Web);
```

**Please Note ereg functions have been deprecated**

Comment: Is the url embedded with other text of in a field by itself?

Comment: Hi Jeff, thanks for the reply, the url and text are both in individual fields. Volkan got the answer below..

Comment: ereg functions have been DEPRECATED please use preg functions - http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if $Loc_Web is just the url without html tags, why don't you use this?

```
echo "<a href='" . $Loc_Web . "'>" . $Loc_Name . "</a>"
```

Comment: Such a simple thing... ...still learning PHP (in a backwards way!!), obviously missed a vital concept with the use of '" .  and . "' to include a variable in a string.. ..not to far from vba, just different syntax...

Comment: it happens. if you find this answer useful you can accept it as an answer. thanks.

Comment: Done! Just waiting for the timer to go! :)